# ZSH: how to repeat argument together with expanded filenames

Tags: zsh, glob

So I'm a neuroimager and I want to open a large number of files. For example:

```
fslview T1.nii.gz _coil_8/run1.nii.gz _coil_8/run2.nii.gz _coil_32/run1.nii.gz _coil_32/run2.nii.gz
```

So I can do this easier using a glob expression in zsh as follows:

```
fslview T1.nii.gz _coil_*/*.nii.gz (<tab>/<enter>)
```

However, what I would actually want is to add an additional colormap range to all the expanded files, so:

```
fslview T1.nii.gz _coil_8/run1.nii.gz -b 300,1500 _coil_8/run2.nii.gz  -b 300,1500_coil_32/run1.nii.gz -b 300,1500 _coil_32/run2.nii.gz -b 300,1500
```

How do I get there?

```
fslview T1.nii.gz _coil_*/*.nii.gz -b 300,1500 (<tab>/<enter>)
```

Doesn't work: then it just add the -b argument to the last filename...

Answer (score 3):

You can replace each file with the file and its range parameter, and then pass back to fslview using xargs:

```
ls _coil_*/*.nii.gz | sed 's/$/ -b 300,1500/' | xargs fslview
```

If there are a lot of files, then you might run into problems if xargs breaks up into separate commands in the wrong place.  You can try `xargs echo fslview` first to see if it's going to be broken up.  You can also intentionally break it up into one call per file, using `xargs -n 3 fslview`

Comment: This also fails when there are malicious filenames containing whitespace. The safe way is appending to an array in a loop.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer (I find bash arrays tricky and would like to see it) but odd filenames can be handled with xargs -0:  `find _coil_* -name \*.nii.gz -print0 | perl -pi -e 's/\000/\000-b\000300,1500\000/g' | xargs -0 -n 3 fslview`

Comment: No need for an answer. Here you go: `tokens=(${mycommand}); for f in *; do tokens=("${arr[@]}" "$f" "${myoption}"); done; "${tokesn[@]}"`. Works with both zsh and bash (I believe). Of course, `"${myoption}"` should be written as multiple tokens if it contains multiple tokens, e.g., in this case, where the OP has `-b 300,1500`.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I changed the array name from `arr` to `tokens` but had one reference to `arr` dangling. By the way, I like your `\000` hack.